# Spectrum of bounded operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $A$ be a bounded operator on complex Hilbert space $H$ such that
$$(1+A^6)(1+A^2+A^4)=0.$$
Let $k\in\mathbb{C}$ be an element of the spectrum $\sigma(A)$.

> How do I show that $k^{12}=1$?

What I know:
The spectrum of $A$ is $\sigma(A)=\{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}:A-\lambda I\text{ is not invertible }\}$. So there exists a non-zero vector $x\in H$ in the kernel of $A-kI$, otherwise said $Ax=kx$.
Then we compute $(1+A^6)(1+A^2+A^4)=1+A^2+A^4+A^6+A^{8}+A^{10}=0$. This gives $(1+k^2+k^4+k^6+k^{8}+k^{10})x=0$. How do I get the statement from this?

Edit: Following @DanielFischer's hint (thank you), we multiply by $(1-A^2)$ to get
$$(1-A^2)(1+A^2+A^4+A^6+A^{8}+A^{10})=1-A^{12}=0.$$
This gives $k^{12}=1$.

Comment: Multiply with $1 - A^2$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you!

Comment: Could you explain how you get from the line with the multiplication to the statement with the eigenvalues?

Comment: @Yuhe Since $1-A^{12}=0$, we see that $0=(1-A^{12})x=x-k^{12}x$. So $k^{12}=1$. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yeah, how do we know that $(1-A^{12})x=x-k^{12}x$ ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that a priori you do not know that the spectrum of $A$ consists of real eigenvalues. That is, if $A - \lambda I$ is not invertible, in the infinite dimensional setting it doesn't always mean you can find $0 \neq x \in H$ such that $Ax = \lambda x$. However, you are given that $A$ satisfies some polynomial equation $p(A) = 0$ with

$$ p(x) = (1 + x^6)(1 + x^2 + x^4). $$

Since

$$ (1 - x^2)(1 + x^6)(1 + x^2 + x^4) = 1 - x^{12}$$

we also know that $g(A) = 0$ with $g(x) := 1 - x^{12}$. By the spectral mapping theorem, we must have $p(\sigma(A)) = \sigma(p(A)) = \{ 0 \}$ which implies that

$$\sigma(A) \subseteq \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \, | \, p(z) = 0 \} = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \, | \, z^{12} = 1 \}. $$